# Combining functions before calling

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am trying to solve the following problem in python: I have got a class (let's call it `Container`) that contains instances of another class (`Worker`, say). The `Worker` instances have a method (`find_value`) that evaluates a rather complicated mathematical formula, which is slightly different for each instance because it depends on their attributes. The `Container` class then contains a method that sums all the contributions from its `Worker` instances. I have for now implemented this essentially as a for-loop iterating over all the instances and calling the `find_value` function for each. Maybe it's easier to understand with a bit of code:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self):
        # Each worker will have different values for its attributes
        self.workers = self.create_workers()

    def find_total_value(self, x, y, z):
        return sum([w.find_value(x, y, z) for w in self.workers])


class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
    # Initialise attributes that affect result returned by self.find_value
    # will be different for each instance

    def find_value(self, x, y, z)
        value = # Some complicated mathematical formula based on numpy 
                # functions that uses the instance attributes
        return value
```

The problem is now the following: I want to use the `find_total_value` function
for numerical simulations (basically solving a time-dependent differential equation with the scipy routines). However, the for-loop in that function slows calculation down a lot, as one might expect. Once all my workers have been created, their attributes do not change any more during the simulation.

So my question is the following: Is it possible to somehow generate the `find_total_value` function as a sum of the other functions beforehand? So that the function acts as if there was just one huge mathematical expression involved (a combination of all the mathematical expressions of the `find_value`functions of the `Worker` instances? I am not sure if I am using the right terminology here, so I am happy to edit my question if further clarifications are required.

Comment: Why do you think what you are proposing would be helpful?

Comment: Are you sure the loop is the costly part of this code? It sounds to me like most of the time will be spent doing the calculation, with only fairly trivial overhead due to the loop and the sum.

Comment: If @joanis is right, using `multiprocessing` to run the `find_value`s in parallel may be more useful.

Comment: @Stephen Rauch Because at each step in the numerical integration the `find_total_value` function is evaluated, which means running a rather slow for-loop that iterates through all the instances and sums the return values of the `find_value` functions. If the `find_total_value` could be generated like the individual `find_value` functions (it should just be the sum of complex mathematical expressions), then no for-loop would be run at each integration step.

Comment: @Quantum, My question was intended to highlight what the other commentators have said.  The for loop will almost certainly not be the slow part, and what you are attempting is unlikely to help speed things up.

Comment: Also, I would be interested in general if a "sum-of-functions" rather than a "sum-of-function-return-values" is something that could be done at all

Comment: You can do something like `self.workers[0].find_value(...) + self.workers[1].find_value(...) + ...` instead or even replace the function calls by inlining the code instead (can be done programmatically e.g. by constructing code as string and feeding it to `exec` or `eval`) but this won't help you much.

Comment: Can the sum be be computed once and and then cached, or must it be completely recalculated it's requested during the simulation?